# How to echo users from table those are logged in?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a list that echos only members who are currently signed in.
Been googling for an answer all day and no luck.

I have an ENUM row for each column that represents when a user is logged on or logged off as `0 or 1`. But how would I go about populating a list of users which only have their ENUM value set to 1?
This is what I got:

```
<?php

    // Create connection
include_once '/phpscripts/credentials.php';
$conn = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{

$sql="SELECT * FROM users";

$INFO=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
While($accounts=mysqli_fetch_assoc($INFO)){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE loggedin = '1'";
    echo $accounts['username'];
    echo "<br>";    
}//end while
}

?>
```

Comment: So, what's the error or problem you are facing?

Comment: No error. It is just populating all users whether they are logged in or not. I just want to populate the ones that are logged in only.

Comment: where does `$accounts` come from? why is the select in a loop, your missing a lot of code here. the 2nd `$sql` is never run etc...

Comment: Move `WHERE loggedin = '1'` to the first SQL query. Remove the second. It's doing nothing.

Comment: This values are from the log in page that directs to this page. They are not needed in this section because they are linked to the session of the user who has logged in to the website. But once the user logs in, he will see a list of all users currently logged in. Thats what I am aiming for.

Comment: That actually worked. Thank you! How would I go about automatically updating this without having to refresh the browser just to see the changes?

Comment: You need to use ajax for that

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/ajax-jquery-ajax.htm

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code. Try the code below

```
  <?php

        // Create connection
    include_once '/phpscripts/credentials.php';
    $conn = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }else{

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE loggedin = '1'";

    $INFO=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($INFO) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($INFO)) {
        echo "Username: " . $row["username"].  "<br>";
    }
    } else {
    echo "0 results";
    }


    }

    ?>
```